# C++ Simple Detours Crashes Target

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, detours

I have this function type from IDA that I am trying to detour:

```
int CTeamInfo__GetNumConnectedClients()
```

so I have the following code into a C++ DLL:

The Original Function:

```
int(__stdcall * CTeamInfo__GetNumConnectedClients)() = (int(__stdcall*)(void))::GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle(TEXT("game.dll")), "?GetNumConnectedClients@CTeamInfo@@QBEHXZ");
```

My Function:

```
 int myCTeamInfo__GetNumConnectedClients()
{
    std::cout << "Called My Function" << std::endl;
    return CTeamInfo__GetNumConnectedClients();
}
```

and my detours:

```
            DetourTransactionBegin();
            DetourUpdateThread(GetCurrentThread());
            DetourAttach(&(PVOID&)CTeamInfo__GetNumConnectedClients, myCTeamInfo__GetNumConnectedClients);
            DetourTransactionCommit();
```

I then try calling myCTeamInfo__GetNumConnectedClients(); and it prints in the console "Called My Function" but then the target process seems to crash.

Here's the pseudo code from IDA:

```
int __thiscall CTeamInfo::GetNumConnectedClients(int this)
{
  int v1; // edi@1
  int result; // eax@1
  int v3; // ebx@2
  int v4; // ebp@2
  int v5; // esi@3
  int v6; // ecx@3
  int v7; // edx@3
  int *v8; // ecx@10
  int v9; // ecx@12
  int v10; // ecx@13
  int v11; // [sp+4h] [bp-10h]@1
  int v12; // [sp+8h] [bp-Ch]@8
  int v13; // [sp+Ch] [bp-8h]@11
  int v14; // [sp+10h] [bp-4h]@1

  v1 = *(_DWORD *)(this + 140);
  result = 0;
  v11 = 0;
  v14 = *(_DWORD *)(this + 144);
  if ( v1 != v14 )
  {
    v3 = *(_DWORD *)(LODWORD(IGame::s_pGame) + 236);
    v4 = *(_DWORD *)(v3 + 4);
    do
    {
      v5 = *(_DWORD *)v1;
      v6 = v4;
      v7 = v3;
      while ( !*(_BYTE *)(v6 + 21) )
      {
        if ( *(_DWORD *)(v6 + 12) >= v5 )
        {
          v7 = v6;
          v6 = *(_DWORD *)v6;
        }
        else
        {
          v6 = *(_DWORD *)(v6 + 8);
        }
      }
      v12 = v7;
      if ( v7 == v3 || v5 < *(_DWORD *)(v7 + 12) )
      {
        v13 = v3;
        v8 = &v13;
      }
      else
      {
        v8 = &v12;
      }
      v9 = *v8;
      if ( v9 != v3 )
      {
        v10 = *(_DWORD *)(v9 + 16);
        if ( v10 )
        {
          if ( !(*(_WORD *)(v10 + 592) & 0x81) )
            ++v11;
        }
      }
      v1 += 4;
    }
    while ( v1 != v14 );
    result = v11;
  }
  return result;
}
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Attach a debugger to the target process and see where it crashes.

Comment: Why do you have __stdcall anywhere in your code?   The function you're trying to detour is certainly a __thiscall function.

Comment: int(__stdcall * CTeamInfo__GetNumConnectedClients)() should be 
int __thiscall * CTeamInfo::GetNumConnectedClients(int this)

have you atleast tested your code?